# How to create a directory in plunker?

Tags: plunker

How do you create a directory in a plunker ? or if there is a directory how do you create a new file/move in that directory ?

Do you need to use an external tool for this ?

`Ex :` I have edited this existing [angular2 plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZfeAwx8ye3xRWjAUSIyn?p=options), I have created **myFile.ts** file, I would like to move it in the **app folder**.
http://plnkr.co/edit/ZfeAwx8ye3xRWjAUSIyn?p=options

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Double click on the filename. Then you can rename it from `myFile` to `app/myFile`.